# JSP Modal Dialog

Tags: jsp, dialog, modal-dialog

I need to get the file name (set path) in a text box. So, I need to POP UP the file browser window and then the file I select should be visible in the text box and send this value to the backend bean.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a JSP specific question.  This is normal HTML behaviour.

```
<form action="blah" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file">
</form>
```

The hard bit is processing the uploading file, I would suggest you should look at [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).